# RelativeLayout Buttons disappear when ScrollView used

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a layout similar to the on used in this [example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-text-and-scrolling-views/index.html?index=..%2F..android-training#4)

[image]

The only difference is that I have 3 buttons that I wanted to add following the ScrollView. Unfortunately as soon as I added the ScrollView, my buttons disappeared off the screen. (When I had a TextView without the ScrollView it was fine).

How can I get my buttons back at the bottom of the screen?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_heading"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/article_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_heading"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"
        android:text="@string/article_subtitle"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/article_scrollview"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_subheading">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
            android:id="@+id/article"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="@string/article_text"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butConnect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_scrollview"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:onClick="onButLoginClicked"
        android:text="@string/but_text_connect"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/butConnect"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:text="@string/but_text_add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butSale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/butAdd"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
        android:text="@string/but_text_sale" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Design your layout carefully and follow design principle**
follow https://developer.android.com/design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article_heading"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="@string/article_title"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article_subheading"
    android:layout_below="@id/article_heading"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"
    android:text="@string/article_subtitle"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_above="@+id/butConnect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/article_scrollview"
    android:layout_below="@id/article_subheading">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/line_spacing"
        android:id="@+id/article"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_regular"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="@string/article_text"/>

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butConnect"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/butAdd"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:onClick="onButLoginClicked"
    android:text="@string/but_text_connect"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/butSale"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:text="@string/but_text_add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/butSale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/button_margin"
    android:text="@string/but_text_sale" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where does this Material/Layout documentation make reference to RelativeLayout?

Comment: And.. why can't the Buttons be specified using layout_below? If I use layout_below, and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" for the Sale button, the Sale button becomes vertically huge and the ScrollView gets completely squashed. I don't understand how you can define in one direction and it will work but it won't work in the other direction. I would gladly read Google's documentation if I could find exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: i was suggest it for design principle not for relative layout , if you thinks its not related then i am sorry for that. by the way did your problem solved with my provided code?

Comment: Yes, your suggestion did solve the problem (thank you). I just wanted to understand why it would work one way and not the other. I'll accept your answer.